# How can I remove these aliases

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update the PSFTP module from the gallery. I used `Remove-Module`, but these three (3) aliases remain. How can I remove them before installing the current PSFTP module?

```
PS C:\src\t\ftp> Get-Command *ftp*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           Move-FTPItem                                       1.6.1.2    PSFTP
Alias           Receive-FTPItem                                    1.6.1.2    PSFTP
Alias           Send-FTPItem                                       1.6.1.2    PSFTP
Function        Get-SFTPChildItem                                  2.0.2      Posh-SSH
Function        Get-SFTPContent                                    2.0.2      Posh-SSH
...

PS C:\src\t\ftp> Remove-Item -Path Alias:Move-FTPItem
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'Alias:\Move-FTPItem' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -Path Alias:Move-FTPItem
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Alias:\Move-FTPItem:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

**Additional information**

I am not sure how `PSFTP` got onto this machine. Using `Uninstall-Module`, even under Run as Administrator, does not work. How might I correctly uninstall this module?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Uninstall-Module -Name PSFTP
PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'PSFTP'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2157 char:21
+ ...        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage
```

The module directory does exist on the machine.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSFTP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Remove-Module` *unloads* a module, but doesn't remove it from the filesystem.**

With `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` at its default (`All`), this means that **the module and its commands are still *discoverable***, even if the module isn't currently loaded (imported).

As it happens, this particular module exports *only* aliases, which is why only they show up in the output from `Get-Command *ftp*`.

While `Get-Command` is able to find aliases from not-currently-loaded (imported) modules, such aliases are *not* present in the `Alias:` drive and attempts to remove them with `Remove-Item Alias:<name>` or, more directly, `Remove-Alias <name>` *fail*.

If you want **to *uninstall* the module** before installing a new version - assuming you've installed it from the PowerShell Gallery, as you say (see update below) - **use [`Uninstall-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/uninstall-module).**

That said, in order **to *update* an installed module**, simply **use [`Update-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/update-module).**
Note that this **performs a *side-by-side* installation**, however: while the newest version does take effect, the previous version is *retained* and requires manual removal, if desired.

---

If the **module *wasn't* installed from the PowerShell Gallery**, ***manual deletion* of its folder is required**:

- **Be sure that no other modules depend on the module to delete**.

  - To **find a module's *dependents***, i.e., other modules that depend on it,  use, e.g. (I'm using module `PackageManagement` as an example, which has module `PowerShellGet` as a dependent):

    ```
    Get-Module -ListAvailable |
      Where-Object { $_.RequiredModules.Name -contains 'PackageManagement' }
    ```

    - Note, however, that there could be *scripts* that also rely on this module, and such uses would be much harder to detect (short of searching all scripts for `#requires -Module` directives, `using -module statements`, `Import-Module` calls, or simply calls to the module's commands that relied on auto-loading the module).
  - To perform the *inverse* operation, i.e. to **find a module's *dependencies***, if any (the modules a given module itself depends on), use, e.g.:

    - `(Get-Module -ListAvailable PowerShellGet).RequiredModules` (there will be no output if there are no dependencies),
    - Similarly, as @lit (the OP) points out, you can query a module available in the PowerShell Gallery for its dependencies online; e.g.:
      `Find-Module -IncludeDependencies PowerShellGet` (this will list the module itself first, followed by its dependencies).
- Depending on the module's installation location, **you may need administrative privileges for removal** (an elevated session).

  - This is definitely the case for `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSFTP`.
    Note that, as a third-party module, `PSFTP` should never have been installed there, because `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` (`$PSHOME\Modules`) is reserved for *system modules* (the ones that ship with PowerShell).
  - Once you've confirmed that it is safe to delete the module folder, use the following (remove the `-WhatIf` to perform actual deletion):

    ```
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSFTP
    ```

---

**Determining a module's location (installation folder):**

- **By *module name*** (e.g., `PSFTP`):

  ```
  Split-Path (Get-Module -ListAvailable PSFTP).Path
  ```

  - `-ListAvailable` ensures that the module is found even if it is not currently imported, but only if it is is located in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`.
  - Conversely, if a module *is* currently imported, but resides in a *nonstandard* directory, you most *omit* `-ListAvailable` in order to find it.
  - *Multiple versions* of a module may be installed and therefore be returned; the one with the highest version number is listed first.

- **By the name of a *command*** exported by the module (e.g., `Send-FTPItem`):

  ```
  Split-Path (Get-Command Send-FTPItem).Module.Path
  ```

  - `Get-Command` finds the command whether or not the containing module is currently imported.
  - If a module containing a command by that name *is* currently loaded (imported), its path is returned.
  - Otherwise, if multiple module versions are installed, the *effective* one is reported, which is the one with the highest version number.

Comment: Many thanks. Actually, I became antsy and found an example on the net of manually deleting the module directory. `Get-Module -Name PSFTP` returned $null. I found the directory and used `Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSFTP' -Recurse -Force` to remove it. It appears to be successful. Have I done any damage? How would I determine if any other modules depend on a given module?

Comment: To identify module dependencies `Find-Module -IncludeDependencies -Name powershellget`

Comment: @lit: Once you've unloaded a module from a session with `Remove-Module`, `Get-Module` won't find it unless you also use `-ListAvailable`, but then only if it's installed in one of the dirs. in `$env:PSModulePath`. (The `Remove-Item` command is also part of the answer). `Find-Module -IncludeDependencies` is handy (I've also added it to the answer), but it is the _opposite_ of what you want here: it finds _dependencies_, whereas here we want _dependents_ - please see my update.

Comment: @lit: As for whether you did damage: `Get-Module -ListAvailable | ? { $_.RequiredModules.Name -eq 'PSFTP' }` would tell if you other _modules_ on your system formally depend on `PSFTP`, but there could still be _scripts_ that reference it - again, please see my update.

Answer (score -1):

You use remove-item, like so:

```
Remove-Item alias:\aliasname
```

example:

[image]

Comment: You'll notice that the OP already unsuccessfully tried `Remove-Item -Path Alias:Move-FTPItem`. Also note that there's a dedicated `Remove-Alias` cmdlet.